# Ignoring the linked object using JAXB annotations, but not the linked object id

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, jpa, jaxb

I'm developing a REST layer based on an auto-generated JPA model. One issue I am having is the JSON/XML being produced has the linked object inside the object I'm getting. Instead of this design, I want the linked object ID, not the whole object.

Is there anyway to modify my model using annotations, to just include the ID of the object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark the property or attribute for the object you want to exclude as `@Transient`.
Then create a new property or attribute to corresponds to the ID of that object i.e. the one you marked `@Transient`.
This may seem a bit wonky, but it will provide the result you are looking for.

NOTE: be sure to use the JAXB `@Transient` annotation, not the JPA `@Transient` annotation.